# How to get multiple SUM() in single query for two conditions

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have table in MS Access:

```
Id | name  | code  |        ttime           | total | type  
-----------------------------------------------------------
1  | Abc   | 123   | 10-Feb-18 4:04:48 PM   | 2.01  | RS
2  | Abd   | 122   | 11-Feb-18 4:04:48 PM   | 3.90  | RS
3  | Abe   | 125   | 12-Feb-18 4:04:48 PM   | 23.00 | WS //other type
4  | Abf   | 124   | 13-Feb-18 4:04:48 PM   | 2.11  | RS
5  | Abg   | 126   | 13-Feb-18 5:04:48 PM   | 8.01  | WS // here too
6  | Abh   | 127   | 14-Feb-18 4:04:48 PM   | 5.01  | RS
7  | Abi   | 128   | 15-Feb-18 4:04:48 PM   | 9.10  | RS
```

I need to take sum of total only RS type in first column and sum of total of WS type in second column as:

```
SELECT SUM(total) AS rstotal, 
       SUM(total) AS wstotal, 
       COUNT(code) 
WHERE ttime > '09-Feb-18 4:04:48 PM'
```

What condition or self join will help and how? The result should be like this:

```
rstotal | wstotal | count
-------------------------
22.13   | 31.01   | 7
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'RS' THEN total END) AS rstotal,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'WS' THEN total END) AS wstotal,
       COUNT(code) AS "count"
FROM table1
WHERE ttime > '09-Feb-18 4:04:48 PM'
```

**EDIT** As Steve pointed out, MS Access doesn't support `CASE WHEN`, so you'll have to use the `IIf()` function:

```
SELECT SUM(IIf(type = 'RS', total, 0)) AS rstotal,
       SUM(IIf(type = 'WS', total, 0)) AS wstotal,
       COUNT(code) AS [count]
FROM table1
WHERE ttime > '09-Feb-18 4:04:48 PM'
```